# New development store - Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Tags: admin, shipping, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I"m getting the above error in a newly locally configured 'testing' store i've set up.  Is there anything in the admin I can change to effectively bypass (or turn all addresses to available) this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide how you want your shipping to work, but at a base level if you switch on flat rate it will always show up.